# How to get linked table value from two different fields in the same row into a single row result set

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a "match" table that shows opponents for a game.  There is a HomeTeamID and an AwayTeamId field in a single row.  The ID fields relate to a "Person" table that has Name information.  What I need is a query to create a single row with the match that contains the person name instead of the id.  I assume it is some form of union and grouping, but for the life of me I can't figure it out.

MATCH TABLE :

```
ID,  DATE,      TIME,    HOMEID, AWAYID
105, 12/1/2018, 5:00 PM, 46,     53
```

PERSON TABLE :

```
ID, NAME
46, John Doe
53, Mike Smith
```

Output needed:

```
105, 12/1/2018, 5:00 PM, 46, John Doe, 53, Mike Smith
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you need to join the person table twice, you must give it two different aliases

```
SELECT m.ID, m.DATE, m.TIME, m.HOMEID, home.NAME, m.AWAYID, away.NAME
FROM
    MATCH m
    INNER JOIN PERSON home
        ON m.HOMEID = home.ID
    INNER JOIN PERSON away
        ON m.AWAYID = away.ID
```